# Two ways of approximating a function?

Tags: analysis, taylor-expansion

Consider the potential $$V(x)=\frac{x^3}{3}-l^2x$$
I would like to approximate this potential around a equilibrium position $x_0$. The first way to do it, and the most rigorous one, is to use the formula :
$$V(x_0+h)\approx V(x_0)+V'(x_0)h+\frac{1}{2}V''(x_0)h^2$$
with $h=x-x_0$. I find that
$$V(x_0+h)\approx \frac{x_0^3}{3}-l^2x_0+x_0h^2$$
But, sometimes, in physics, in order to approximate potential, we approximate directly in the formula that gives the potential. In this case, we have :
$$V(x_0+h)=\frac{1}{3}(x_0+h)^3-l^2(x_0+h)=\frac{1}{3}x_0^3(1+\frac{h}{x_0})^3-l^2x_0-l^2h$$
By using the Taylor approximation :
$$(1-x)^{\alpha}\approx 1+\alpha x + \frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)}{2!}x^2\Rightarrow V(x_0+h)=\frac{x_0^3}{3}(1-3\frac{h}{x_0}+\frac{6}{2}\frac{h^2}{x_0^2})-l^2x_0-l^2h$$
Hence
$$V(x_0+h)=\frac{x_0^3}{3}-x_0^2h+x_0h^2-l^2x_0-l^2h$$
we is not the result that I found using the formula given in the second equation $V(x_0+h)=\frac{x_0^3}{3}-l^2x_0+x_0h^2$
I don't really know why I get this difference. Any help would be appreciated,

Comment: You first Taylor expansion is wrong. And your second expansion seems to be around $x_0+h$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I don't think that my first Taylor expansion is wrong, since $V''(x)=2x$ we have that $V''(x_0)h^2/2=x_0h^2$ ...

Comment: It IS wrong, the linear term is missing.

Comment: what do you mean by linear term ? Maybe I understand : $V'(x_0)h$ is missing ! Because in this case is it $0$ since it is equilibrium position, but I don't take it to be $0$ in the second computation. But if I take into acount the linear term, i get for the first expansion $V(x)=x_0^3/3-l^2x_0+x_0h^2+x_0^2h-l^2h$ which is not what I get for the second expansion;

Answer (score 1):

By direct computation,

$$V(x_0+h)=\frac{(x_0+h)^3}3-l^2(x_0+h)=V_0(x_0)+x_0^2h-l^2h+x_0h^2+\frac{h^3}3$$

and by Taylor,

$$V(x_0+h)=V(x_0)+(x_0^2-l^2)h+2x_0\frac{h^2}2+2\frac{h^3}{3!}.$$

The two expression coincide.

Comment: you make your Taylor expansion at order $3$and I do it at order $2$. This does not really answer my question :( Or maybe I did not understand what do you mean. In your first computation, you don't make any approximation right ? In my second computation, I approximate (order two), the different terms in the potential